# Dynamic layout in Vue 3 with Vite

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vite

New to Vue and Vite but trying to get dynamic layouts working properly here. I believe I have what is needed but the issue it the meta seems to always come up as an empty object or `undefined`.

**AppLayout.vue**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  import AppLayoutDefault from './stub/AppLayoutDefault.vue'
  import { markRaw, watch } from 'vue'
  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

  const layout = markRaw(AppLayoutDefault)
  const route = useRoute()

  console.log('Current path: ', route.path)
  console.log('Route meta:', route.meta)

  watch(
    () => route.meta,
    async (meta) => {
      try {
        const component = await import(`./stub/${meta.layout}.vue`)
        layout.value = component?.default || AppLayoutDefault
      } catch (e) {
        layout.value = AppLayoutDefault
      }
    },
    { immediate: true }
  )
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="layout"> <router-view /> </component>
</template>
```

**App.vue**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  import AppLayout from '@/layouts/AppLayout.vue'
</script>
<template>
  <AppLayout>
    <router-view />
  </AppLayout>
</template>
```

Each and every route has the appropriate meta set with a property called `layout`.

I just can't seem to get he layout applied correctly on the first load or any click of a link in the navbar(which are just router-link) for that matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem is `layout` is initialized as `markRaw()`, which is not a reactive `ref`:

```js
const layout = markRaw(AppLayoutDefault) // ❌ not reactive
```

### Solution

1. Initialize `layout` as a `ref`.
2. Instead of watching the full `route` object, watch `route.meta?.layout` because that's the only relevant field for the handler.
3. Wrap `layout`'s new values with `markRaw()` to avoid reactivity on the component definition.

```js
const layout = ref() 1️⃣

watch(
  () => route.meta?.layout as string | undefined, 2️⃣
  async (metaLayout) => {
    try {
      const component = metaLayout && await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `./${metaLayout}.vue`)
      layout.value = markRaw(component?.default || AppLayoutDefault) 3️⃣
    } catch (e) {
      layout.value = markRaw(AppLayoutDefault) 3️⃣
    }
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-router-meta-layout?file=src/layouts/AppLayout.vue)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Tony is great. But you need to add computed inside the watch because it will prevent code execution for the very first "layout" variable initialized which is still undefined and it will cause unnecessary rendering. So, please add the computed function inside the watch function. Also you need to watch "route.path" not the "route.meta?.layout".

```
import DefaultLayout from '@/layouts/Default.vue'
import { markRaw, ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import { computed, watch } from '@vue/runtime-core'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const layout = ref()
const route = useRoute()

watch(
  computed(() => route.path), async () => {
    let metaLayout = route.meta?.layout

    try {
      const metaLayoutComponent = metaLayout && await import(`./layouts/${metaLayout}.vue`)

      layout.value = markRaw(metaLayoutComponent?.default || DefaultLayout)
    } catch (error) {
      layout.value = markRaw(DefaultLayout)
    }
  }
);
```